# How to restore Postgresql dump file in MariaDB database

Tags: mariadb, database-migration

I have a postgresql dump file and I want to restore it in mysql/MariaDB database. Have any suggestion please help me to restore it.

When ever I am trying to import showing me below errors.

Error
SQL query: Copy

### --
-- PostgreSQL database dump

-- Dumped from database version 13.4
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 13.6

-- Started on 2022-12-08 11:11:06

SET statement_timeout = 0;
MySQL said: Documentation

#1193 - Unknown system variable 'statement_timeout'

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: These are different RDBMS, using different dialects of SQL - that dump file isn't universally compatible. You might want to restore the dump to a PostgreSQL instance using `pg_restore` or `psql`, then use [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/migrate/) to migrate it to your MySQL/MariaDB.

Comment: Sorry I am unable to migrate in MySQL/MariaDB by using MySQL Workbench. Will you tell me the steps of migration process.

Answer (score 1):

These are different RDBMS, using different dialects of SQL - that dump file isn't universally compatible.
If you have the access to the database this dump file came from, you can skip the first two steps:

1. [Set up a PostgreSQL instance](https://www.postgresql.org/download/).
2. Restore the dump to that instance using [`pg_restore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html), [`psql -f`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html), [PGAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/backup_and_restore.html).
3. Use [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/migrate/) to migrate it to your MySQL/MariaDB. Most modern SQL client apps/IDEs might have similar options. They should also be able to handle loading the dump file to PostgreSQL the same way `psql` or `pg_dump` would.

   There's also [`pg2mysql`](https://github.com/vmware-archive/pg2mysql) but while it might still work, a 5 year
   old repo doesn't look too promising.

Comment: Sorry I have tried that and I am unable to migrate in MySQL/MariaDB by using MySQL Workbench. Will you tell me the steps of migration process.

Comment: You'll have to open a thread with some specifics of what went wrong. Try to describe step by step what you did and attach messages, errors and warnings as text, whenever possible. Keep in mind it's useful for people who'll search for a similar problem or error message in the future and pictures won't be found by those searches.

Comment: I have installed workbench, postgresql and PgAdmin. That after restore dump file into postgres database. That after open workbench app and try to connect using 127.0.0.1 host name and port 5432 and the use the password to connect but it showing error to connect.

Comment: @Anjan Opening up a separate thread in the form of comments to an existing one will make it difficult to format, edit and follow. You can leave this answer anaccepted and unrated until you manage to make it work, but the troubleshooting process of each of these steps will really be easier in separate thread with a specific question and description. Most of what you're describing is likely already asked&answered many times over: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgres%5D+cannot+connect+to+local) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=workbench+cannot+connect+to+local).

Comment: will you plz see the above answer, which is posted by me and there have error message details.

Answer (score 0):

After install qsqlodbc and msodbc complete my connection will work but here showing some error on page of `"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\db_postgresql_re_grt.py"`

```
seq_details_query = """SELECT min_value, max_value, start_value, 
increment_by, last_value, is_cycled, cache_value
FROM "%s"."%s" """
```

And I replaced it below code and workable to connection

```
seq_details_query = """SELECT min_value, max_value, start_value, 
increment_by, last_value, cycle as is_cycled, cache_size as cache_value
FROM pg_catalog.pg_sequences
WHERE schemaname = '%s' AND sequencename = '%s' """
```

After it complete next step go to migration process showing me below error.

```
- Finalizing foreign key migration...
- Migration finished

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\workbench\wizard_progress_page_widget.py", line 197, in thread_work
    self.func()
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\migration_object_migration.py", line 117, in task_migrate
    self.main.plan.migrate()
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\migration.py", line 510, in migrate
    self.migrationTarget.catalog = self.migrationSource.migration.migrateCatalog(self.state, self.migrationSource.catalog)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'db_mysql_Catalog'
ERROR: Migrate Selected Objects: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'db_mysql_Catalog'
Failed
```

Comment: I think you shouldn't try to migrate `pg_toast`, `pg_catalog` and `informations_schema` even if you see them as an option. If you happened to save some relations in those schemas, you can first move them out by `alter sequence your_sequence_name set schema public;`, `alter table your_table_name set schema public;`, etc. In normal circumstances all your stuff should be in schema public or other schemas created and specified by your queries, not in any of those three.

Comment: Also, don't post questions/problems/additions to your question as an answer. If it's tightly related, you can edit the question and add details. Otherwise it's fine to open a new thread.